# whitespace PHP link

Tags: php, html, string

I'm using PHP to send a string with $_GET to another webpage.

My main issue is when I try to see the whole string in my link just appear the first word **"Im"**.

I'm pretty sure it is by double quotes but I'm not sure to do this.

```
<a href="edit.php?title=library&description=Im" going="" to="" the="" library="" tomorrow="">
```

I try to put this in my PHP code to replace `""` character to `''` but it doesn't work.

```
$length = strlen($_GET['description']);
$i=0;

do{

   $_GET['description'][$i] = preg_replace('/["]/', '', $_GET['description][$i]);

   $i++;
}while($i < $length);
```

My PHP link is the next:

```
echo "<a href=edit.php?title=$_GET[title]&description=$_GET[description]>";
```

If anyone knows what's going on, please help me.

Comment: Show how you're creating the link. The problem is that you didn't put the URL in quotes.

Comment: It should be `<a href="edit.php?title=library&description=Im going to the library tomorrow">`

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape user input on HTML pages https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Comment: If I try to replace "preg_replace" by "htmlspecialchars" it doesn't work neither.

Comment: `echo "<a href='edit.php?title=$_GET[title]&description=$_GET[description]'>";` Remember to add `' '` quotes for the other href as well.

Comment: Hi @NcXNav seems it work, but now appear %20 in my link. How can I solve it?                               ```@IP/Ex2/edit.php?title=library&description=Im%20going%20to%20the%20library%20tomorrow ```

Comment: Hi @javi-ur96 I think it's normal. Try to print out `$_GET[description]` value, and I think it should be correct. `%20` is just a URL Encode for `space`.

Comment: Hi @NcXNav you're right! I appreciate your help

Comment: @javi-ur96 No problem, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function?

```
// if $_GET["title"] = "Im going to the library tomorrow" ...
echo "<a href=edit.php?title=" . rawurlencode($_GET["title"]) . "&description=" . rawurlencode($_GET["description"]) . ">";
```

You may need to use [`rawurldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) when you receive this.

Comment: I haven't but I will.